# Job offer and scholarship

Tags: job-offer

I got a job offer which I have agreed on and i am looking forward to. However, few months ago I applied for a scholarship and recently I received news that my application for the scholarship is still being considered.

I am to report for duty for my new job next week. But if I received the scholarship, i will need to start my studies in late September. I am not sure what to do because there is still a possibility that i will not get the scholarship. (The scholarship is for oversea studies).

But if i get the scholarship after working for a few weeks, i will need to quit the job. Should i let the future employer know about this situation?

Comment: This is a common topic and I'm fairly sure we've recently had a near-exact duplicate of this but people word these questions so strangely that I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that it is a scolarship does not change the equation. And generally, it is recommended not to tell anything at your working place until you get something clear (job offer, contract... or scolarship acceptance).

Your work probably includes a trial time (typically a few months) which is also for such cases.

So for the time being, no need to tell them anything. But as soon as you get a positive confirmation (possibly in paper form), do tell them as soon as possible.

You might want to check your contract to see how long you have to work when resigning. It's usually different during the trial, but both should be in your contract.